# Multiple If conditional formula but tricky one

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Excel Column M = start time and Column N = End time

- If column M and N is blank need to display results as "Not yet started"
- If Column M has any values/time Need to display as " In progress"
- If Column N has any values/time Need to display as " Completed"

I have tried with IF formula which is not giving expected result

```
=IF(M 2="","not yet started",IF(M 2="M 2>0","in progress","Completed"))
```

AM not sure which is better If or any other formula

Much appreciated for your response

Answer (score 3):

Use a nested IF, but change the logic a little:

```
=IF(AND(M2="",N2=""),"Not Started",IF(N2<>"","Completed","In Progress"))
```

Or:

```
=IF(N2="",IF(M2="","Not Started","In Progress"),"Completed")
```

Comment: Thank you so much - perfect answer